# Parent fields are all nil when accessed by child (embedded 1-n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a 1-n relationship defined as follows:

```
class User
  field :email, type: String
  embeds_many :papers
end

class Paper
  embedded_in :user
end
```

If I try and access the parent fields (user) from the child (paper) like so:

```
User.all.map(:papers).flatten.first.user.email
```

Then I get nil :(

Accessing like this works fine though:

```
User.all.first.papers.first.user.email
```

Comment: You probably wanted to use `User.all.map(&:papers)` and forgot the ampersand?

Comment: Yep! -10 internets for me for being a silly sausage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mispelling lire report on comment. To call a method on a map,you need use `&` before your symbol.

Try:

`User.all.map(&:papers).flatten.first.user.email`